# Help Solving a logarithmic equation $P\times\log{(1-\frac{a}{nP})} = -b\times\log{(1+\frac{c}{n})}$ for P where P>0

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

I have tried using algebraic Logarithm and exponent rules but I cannot get P into a common form. I get P in exponent and standard form or I get P in Logarithmic and standard form

My attempt so far:

$10^{P\times\log{(1-\frac{a}{nP})}}=10^{-b\times\log{(1+\frac{c}{n})}}$

$10^{P}10^{\log{(1-\frac{a}{nP})}}=10^{-b}10^{\log{(1+\frac{c}{n})}}$

$10^{P}(1-\frac{a}{nP})=10^{-b}(1+\frac{c}{n})$

$10^{P}-\frac{a10^{P}}{nP}=10^{-b}+\frac{c10^{-b}}{n}$

From here it really looks like the product log function could apply but I cannot get the equation into an $a^{x}+x=b$ form

From here I am genuinely lost as I've gone in a circle.

$nP10^{P}-a10^{P}=nP10^{-b}+cP10^{-b}$

$nP10^{P}-a10^{P}=P(n10^{-b}+c10^{-b})$

$10^{P}(nP-a)=P(n10^{-b}+c10^{-b})$

$10^{P}(nP-a)=P(n10^{-b}+c10^{-b})$

Comment: But the logarithm of $1$ is $0$... did you copy this correctly? Also, please share the full attempt.

Comment: @SeanRoberson thankyou, I have corrected the title, new to the site

Comment: I think you can simplify your expression to $$(1+x)^{x}=\alpha$$But I'm not sure it has a nice analytical form

Comment: This will not have a nice algebraic solution. Look up Lambert W function.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I have completed adding my full attempt

Comment: @EthanBolker I've looked into the W function and I think it could do the trick but I am having a very hard time getting this function into the form of $a^{x}+x=b$. Any suggestions to separate the exponential term from the non exponential term?

Comment: In case it helps, you can get to $$(e-fx)^x = 0.1 \\ x\equiv P^{-1}, \;e \equiv \frac{1}{d}, \; f \equiv \frac{a}{nd}, \; d\equiv 10^{-b}(1+\frac{c}{n})$$