# How to evaluate $(1-aP)^P=d$ for P where $P>0$ and a & d are known

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, finance

For context I am working trying to work out a formula based on the payout annuity formulas.
With these forums I have been able to derive the expected term for a given payment:

Standard payout annuity for amount: $A = \frac{P(1-(1+\frac{R}{n})^{-nt})}{\frac{R}{n}}$

Solved for Time: $t = \frac{-ln(1-\frac{AR}{nP})}{nln{1+\frac{R}{n}}}$

Furthermore the Interest can be calculated as: $I = ntP-A$

I am looking to Solve the payment $P$ where in terms of a desired interest. Putting the two equations together and combining constants for simplicity I get:

$P = \frac{c}{n}\frac{1}{t}$ and $\frac{1}{t} = \frac{nln(b)}{-ln(1-aP)}$ where $a = \frac{AR}{n}$, $b = 1+\frac{R}{n}$, and $c = I-A$

I can simplify the equation into the following form:

$P = \frac{cln(b)}{-ln(1-\frac{a}{P})} \to 0 = cln(b)+Pln(1-\frac{a}{P})$ exponentiating

$e^{0} = e^{ln(cb)+Pln(1-\frac{a}{P})} = e^{ln(b^{c})}e^{ln{(1-\frac{a}{P})}^P}$

$(1-\frac{a}{P})^{P} = d$ where $d = \frac{1}{b^{c}}$

How can I evaluate the need P from this form?

Comment: Is this a repost of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4838248/help-solving-a-logarithmic-equation-p-times-log1-fracanp-b-times-lo)? If so, software gives a productlog solution for it.

Comment: Hello @ТymaGaidash with regards to that question, I restarted from the beginning to see if I could get the equation into a product log form. I could not but I was able to get it into this form. is there a way to use the product log to evaluate P?

Comment: In your previous question, you can rearrange into $p\ln(1-\frac up)=x,x=  -b\times\log{(1+\frac{c}{n})},u=\frac an$ and have [this solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+for+p%3A+p+ln%281-c%2Fp%29%3Dx) which works numerically

Comment: @TymaGaisash ok, I'll re-open that question and try to work through it

Comment: @copperpen There is something contradictory. Solving $I=ntP-A$ for $P$ gives $$P=\frac{I+A}{nt} \quad (*)$$. Then $P=\frac{c}{n}\cdot  \frac{1}{t}=\frac{I-A}{n}\cdot  \frac{1}{t}$, using $c = I-A$. This is a contradiction to $(*)$.